# Существует ли аналог open_basedir (PHP) или fs-lock (Node.JS) в Python 3?

Tags: python, ос, path, доступ, права-доступа

В угоду безопасности возникла необходимость запретить скрипту доступ к каталогам ниже родительского. Существует что-нибудь аналогичное параметру open_basedir *(PHP)* или пакету fs-lock *(Node.JS)* в Python 3?

Comment: Это всё костыли, помещайте программу в изолированный контейнер. Вообще, попытки создания песочницы в питоне признаны провалившимися

Comment: И ещё, похоже, этот самый fs-lock тоже можно обойти https://github.com/YahooArchive/fs-lock/issues/5

Comment: @andreymal, контейнер - одно из решений, но хотелось бы обойтись малой кровью. А проблема process.bindings не решается его переопределением? Типа process.bindings = false; (только предположение)?

Comment: Конкретно node.js я в этом плане особо не тыкал, но когда люди пытались делать песочницу в python, то неизбежно находились всякие разные хитрые пути обхода подобных решений. Впрочем, это про CPython; у других реализаций вроде PyPy/Jython/IronPython, если верить вики, какие-то намёки на песочницу вроде есть, но они подойдут далеко не везде (да и лично я их не пробовал)

Comment: @andreymal, Хочу поинтересоваться. А "доработка" модулей os.py (и возможно sys.py если такой модуль лежит файлом) + запрет на изменение последних не помогут решить проблему?

Comment: Не поможет, можно влезть в пространство какого-нибудь другого модуля и попытаться вытащить из него всё что нужно. И отловить все такие возможности влезания очень сложно. Кроме того, встроенные (built-in) модули модифицировать штатным путём вы в принципе не сможете, такие как `_io`, `posix` или `nt` — тут только редактировать исходный код самого́ питона на Си, что само по себе уже весьма сложная задача